# Code compilation under g++ compared to clang++

Tags: c++, clang++

I have some code that compiles in `-m32`, `-m64`, `-mx32` in `g++`, in `clang++` it compiles `-m32`, `-m64`, `-mx32` but `-mx32` is unable to link emitting the error copied bellow.

Does any body has experience with the above situation ?
What should I look at ? Is a bug of clang++ ?

> fatal error: error in backend: Cannot select: 0x5bd7ec8: ch = brind
>   0x5ba0fc8:1, 0x5ba0fc8 [ORD=1] [ID=10] 0x5ba0fc8: i32,ch = load
>   0x5ba3d20:1, 0x5c8c1e0, 0x5ba3f30 [ORD=1] [ID=9]
>   0x5c8c1e0: i32 = add 0x5bd80d8, 0x5ba33d8 [ORD=1] [ID=8] 0x5bd80d8:
>   i32 = shl 0x5ba3d20, 0x5ba30c0 [ORD=1] [ID=7] 0x5ba3d20: i32,ch =
>   CopyFromReg 0x56b46c0, 0x5bd6678 [ORD=1] [ID=5] 0x5bd6678: i32 =
>   Register %vreg188 [ID=1] 0x5ba30c0: i8 = Constant<2> [ID=4] 0x5ba33d8:
>   i32 = X86ISD::Wrapper 0x5bd6ca8 [ID=6] 0x5bd6ca8: i32 =
>   TargetJumpTable<0> [ID=3] 0x5ba3f30: i32 = undef [ID=2] In function:
>   _Z8toString3objbbi clang: error: clang frontend command failed with exit code 70 (use -v to see invocation) Ubuntu clang version
>   3.5.0-4ubuntu2 (tags/RELEASE_350/final) (based on LLVM 3.5.0) Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnux32 Thread model: posix clang: note: diagnostic
>   msg: PLEASE submit a bug report to http://bugs.debian.org/ and include
>   the crash backtrace, preprocessed source, and associated run script.
>   clang: note: diagnostic msg:
>
> ---
>
> PLEASE ATTACH THE FOLLOWING FILES TO THE BUG REPORT: Preprocessed
>   source(s) and associated run script(s) are located at: clang: note:
>   diagnostic msg: /tmp/main-eedcc1.cpp clang: note: diagnostic msg:
>   /tmp/main-eedcc1.sh clang: note: diagnostic msg:
>
> ******************** napl21.mk:91: recipe for target 'Debug/main.cpp.o' failed make[1]: *** [Debug/main.cpp.o] Error 70
>   make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/gk/.codelite/workspace01/napl21'
>   Makefile:4: recipe for target 'All' failed make: *** [All] Error 2 0
>   errors, 8 warnings

Comment: Well, did you `PLEASE submit a bug report to http://bugs.debian.org/ and include the crash backtrace, preprocessed source, and associated run script.` ?

Comment: if you read the message, yes clang crashed so it is a bug of clang. try use newest of clang and if bug remain then follow the steps to report the bug

Comment: Thanks for your confirmation, I will submit.

Answer (score 0):

Versions of your g++ and clang++ could be quite useful.  Architecture as well.

One possible explanation could be that you are trying to link binary objects and/or libraries, produced by different versions of compilers.  For instance, some SUN C libraries with clang libraries.

Practical steps:

1. Do clean build
2. Get latest clang
3. Compile and see if it works
4. If not, come back with more details as per above :)

Comment: Version is: "Ubuntu clang version 3.5.0-4ubuntu2 (tags/RELEASE_350/final) (based on LLVM 3.5.0) Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu Thread model: posix" .

Comment: Have you tried doing a clean build?  Any external libraries you are linking against (libraries, not coming from Ubuntu-supported deb packages)?

Comment: This could be eventually a clang bug, as others have suggested.